# How can I insert a variable into my farm command - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My goal is to make a farming command, I want the user to enter an amount of fertilizer to add to a plant.

So far my command looks like this:

```
    if f'!use 20 Dünger' in message.content:
        Düngen= await message.channel.send('Deine Pflanzen wurden Gedüngt in 30 Minuten kannst du sie abbauen')
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await Düngen.edit(content='**Deine Pflanzen müssen abgebauen werden sonst gehen sie kapput')
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Your question isnt quite clear

Comment: If someone does not enter the number 20 but e.g. 12 the command should still be executed

Comment: jjoy's answer isnt the best but it's the right direction, you're going to want to split up the part that invokes the action, aka !use, 20 and Dünger. You could do that in a command as in jjoy's answer, but using .split to split message contents like: `contents = message.content.split()` and then checking content[0] == !use would work too (i advise using the commands for larger bots though as it adds a lot of functionality). In commands you would take all the arguments as parameters or catch them all with *args

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to pass an argument into a command wouldn't something like this be ideal?

```
@client.commands()
async def use(ctx, amount):
    if int(amount) == 20:
        #rest of the code
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear and you would need to edit it, as we can't tell what your intentions were to make this question.

Using a command decorator and a `wait_for`, seems like what want to achieve. This can wait for a message input after using a command to function it. In your case, you are trying to farm with a maximum of 20 fertilizer.

Here's what I have put together.

```
@client.command()
async def use(ctx, item="fertilizer")

        message = await ctx.send("How many fertilizer do you want to use? Enter 1 - 20")

        msg = await client.wait_for(
            'message', timeout=30, check=lambda message: message.author == member)

        if msg.content.lower() == "20":
                await ctx.send("You put fertilizer on your farm!")
                return
```

I've left lot's of room for you to complete the rest of this code, and adding exactly what you would like. Again, it's hard for people to understand exactly what you would like in your answer but hope this fills in some blank spaces.